# Setting up integration tests in an ember-cli app - how to access module() and visit()?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, integration-testing, qunit, ember-cli

This page, 
[ember-cli testing](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#testing),
 says "The included tests demonstrate how to write both unit tests and acceptance/integration tests using the new 
[ember-testing package](http://ianpetzer.wordpress.com/2013/06/14/getting-started-with-integration-testing-ember-js-using-ember-testing-and-qunit-rails/)."

However in order to get an integration test working, I need to find `module` and `visit` or any of the [ember test helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/).
Where are they found, where can I import them from?

---

Details:

The closest I have found to `module` is `moduleFor`, which can be imported from `ember-qunit`. Module for is not suitable for integration testing as I am testing an entire page or series of pages within the app, rather than an individual model, route, controller, view, etc.

My best guess is that `visit` can be found within Ember itself, but I am not sure where to import it from.

Using neither `module` nor `moduleFor`, I am able to run the tests, but they error out:

> ReferenceError: visit is not defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ember-cli generates start-app.js file which includes function that prepare ember for testing.

in your integration test file...

```
import startApp from '../../helpers/start-app'; // change this due to your folder hierarchy

var App;

module('Integration Test', {
  setup: function(){
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown: function(){
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
}
```

now your Ember App is ready for testing. You can use ember-testing helpers.

Comment: Is there a way to move this boilerplate setup code from **every** test to a single, dry place?

Comment: @shredding - if you use ember-cli to generate your test files it will already have all this boilerplate set up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @saygun`s answer.
As of now instead of module we will be using moduleForComponent or moduleFor as needed.
Eg:

```
moduleForComponent('comp-name', 'Integration | Component | comp name', {
  integration: true,
  setup: function(){
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown: function(){
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});
```